# eclipse or Myeclipse Debug "Display" view does not show code assist

Tags: java, debugging, view, code-assist

About eclipse debug "Display" view

*Display view allows you to manipulate live code in a scrapbook type fashion (see Figure 8). To manipulate a variable, simply type the name of the variable in the Display view, and you'll be greeted with a familiar content assist.*

`http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/`

I have stopped at break point and used Display  view for some code inspection and execution but I could not get the code assistance in the Display view. Although copy paste a code and executing it works ok.

Having code assist will be very helpful, I get the code assist when defining **Breakpoint** condition.

Regards,
Rashid

Comment: Eclipse thinks they fixed this bug in [2004](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=61102), but it's still happening for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> not get you content assist? It does for me. I don't think it's automatic unless you are trying to call a method on an object by typing the `.` after the object.

Comment: So out of topic, it's about the display view that should display on Debug perspective, it's disappeared and can't get it back. It's not about auto complete during coding.

Comment: The point is moot, given the time difference, but I think you need to check the question again: "I have stopped at break point and used Display view for some code inspection and execution but I could not get the code assistance in the Display view."

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue that all the debug tabs are lost and could not restore it via *Windows > Show View > Variable/Display*, it always remains disappear.

Now I just got things back by resetting the Debug perspective to get the **Variable** and **Display** tab back.

[image: Resetting Debug perspective to get missing tab]